# Forward Auditd logs to one servers and analyze using aureport

Tags: rhel, rsyslog, linux-audit

I configured auditd in two RHEL servers with required rules. The audit logs are as expected. 
I want to forward these logs to a central server so that the analysis will be easy. 
I tried the two approaches mentioned in this link 
[Send auditd logs to a remote log server in Red Hat Enterprise](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28676)

Issue with approach 1 (Send to a remote auditd server): The logs from all clients are appended to a single file. I am not able to get separate reports for each client.

Issue with approach 2 (Send to a remote syslog server): The logs in the server side has extra words at the start of the line. These are added to the actual auditd log from the client

> "**Jan 12 16:38:22 MahineName audispd: node= MahineName** “type=USER_TTY msg=audit(1484257088.191:1486822)

Due to this, aureport is not able to parse these logs and show zero events.

Please suggest a proper approach to collect all audit logs separately from all clients and run aureport on these

OS : RHEL 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to filter aureport by 'node'. 
This should work for me

[aureport](https://linux.die.net/man/8/aureport)

```
--node node-name
Only select events originating from node name string for processing in the reports. The default is to include all nodes. Multiple nodes are allowed.
```